# Command window closing very quickly when running batch script with system()

Tags: c++, batch-file, c++builder

I have an application developed using Borland C++Builder (Embarcadero nowadays) on Windows 10.

I want to launch a script contained in a `.bat` file from my app, using
the following code:

```cpp
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    system("myfile.bat");
}
```

However, the command window appears then exits very fast, and I have no time to see the result.

I have added a `pause` command in the `.bat` file, but without success.

Below is the code for my `.bat` file:

```
@echo off
"./ttpmacro.exe" /I "./binary.ttl"
pause
```

Is there any solution to this issue?

Comment: If the window is opening, then clearly the batch file is being run, as that runs within a cmd window. What we therefore need from you is the entire content of that batch file. You have stated that the `pause` command has made no difference, so clearly the batch file is broken before it reaches that point. We cannot help you to fix that issue, unless we can also replicate that file, and reproduce your issue. Please use the [edit] button, and submit the content of that batch file, within a code box, in order to receive focused assistance.

Comment: On Windows, `system("myfile.bat");` will call `CreateProcess()` to execute `cmd.exe /C myfile.bat`, so it is possible that `myfile.bat` is not even running at all (ie, if `cmd.exe` can't find the file, etc), but the `cmd` window is still opening because `cmd.exe` is run briefly. Is `myfile.bat` in the current working directory of the process that is calling `system()`? Or at least on the system search path? Do you have the same problem if you specify a full path to `myfile.bat` instead of a relative path?

Comment: If you really want to capture the output, consider calling `CreateProcess()` directly so you can redirect the spawned process's `STDOUT`/`STDERR` to a pipe that you create and can then read from at your leisure.

Comment: Please at least read the Microsoft documentation for the Windows kernel library function [CreateProcess](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) which is used on Windows by `system()` to start `%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe` with the argument `/c` and the string written in your C++ code as additional arguments. How these arguments are interpreted by `cmd.exe` is described by the usage help output on running `cmd /?` in a command prompt window. Please read very carefully about the function parameter `lpCurrentDirectory`.

Comment: Your code expects that the current directory defined by the parent process on starting the executable compiled from your code is the directory containing your executable. There is one chance that this expectation is true, but thousands of chances that any other directory is the current directory on starting your executable which means the batch file is also not found by `cmd.exe` and if it would be found via environment variable `PATH`, `ttpmacro.exe` and `binary.ttl` are perhaps not found next by `cmd.exe` in the current directory.

Comment: There can be used on Windows the function [GetModuleFileName](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-getmodulefilenamew) to get the fully qualified file name of the executable from which the full path can be extracted for usage on running `cmd.exe` to process the batch file with its fully qualified file name. Inside the batch file can be used `"%~dp0ttpmacro.exe" /I "%~dp0binary.ttl"`. `%~dp0` references the full path of the batch file always ending with a backslash. That is the reason why the concatenations with the file names are without ``\``.

Comment: Please read also the Microsoft documentation about [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file). The directory separator on Windows is ``\`` and not `/` as on Linux/Mac. In most cases the usage of `/` in file/folder name strings work thanks to Windows file IO functions which replace them by ``\`` before passing the file/folder name string to the file system, but there are use cases which result in unexpected behavior on using `/` in file/folder strings or wildcard patterns. So use ``\`` in file/folder name strings in a batch file.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Thanks for your support. Can you give me more details on how I can redirect the error showed rapidly by the cmd window for example on a .txt file.

Comment: @geek225 [Creating a Child Process with Redirected Input and Output](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/creating-a-child-process-with-redirected-input-and-output)

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Thanks very much for your support. It was finally a problem to the path (working directory) of the .bat file.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved my issue by changing the path of the working directory. I have modified the path directory of the file "mybat.file" and then all things got OK.